# Authentication using an intermediate web app as an openid client

Tags: authentication, web-application, openid

There are 3 different web apps:
X: A resource provider that provides details about a user (implements authorization part of openid protocol).
Y: Web service (implements openid client) that gets the user details from X
Z: Web app that wants to use the user in its app logic.

I understand, that it would be better to not have the Y at all and directly implement the openid client in the Z. However, let's say that the Z does not "want" to implement it and wants some quicker solution.

A possible quicker solution:

1. Web app Z provides a server side API key to app Y.
2. Web service app Y uses this key to send user information it has retrieved from openid protocol.
3. Web app Z gets receives user information (creates it if it's not on the system yet), create a session and responds with redirect including that session cookie.

Would this approach be valid? What are the main red flags in this scenario in general?

Comment: X is the OIDC Provider, Y is the web service and Z is a web app. There is no intermediate web app in your architecture. Z doesn't have to implement anything except for handling the redirects.

Comment: No need for server side API key. Static API key defeats the purpose of using OIDC. Let web service Y to get the ID token and share it directly with the web service Z which will send it to the web app Z. Web service Z should at least implement the verification of ID token using keys which also can be obtained from web service Y.